# Is it possible to edit file and commit github/bitbucket from browser

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-api, git-commit, bitbucket-api

I want to use editor in browser and save in github without server. Just like text editor in github/bitbucket could new file and save it

I want to know are there any REST api of this 2 services to easily commit file like that

Or a git library in js that could work without the need to pull all files in to our machine

edit:

After 2018 both service already expose their API. This question is outdated

Comment: Update Aug. 2021: GH Codespace is now available. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747270/6309)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you're looking for an online code editor that you can connect to github or bitbucket then you could take a look at these:

- [Codeanywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/)
- [Cloud9](https://c9.io/)

If you're looking to develop such an editor yourself, you could just start from github or bitbucket's REST API documentation:

- [Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/)
- [Bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/latest/bitbucket-rest.html)

And just choose the javascript REST library of your preference to interact with those APIs.

For Github: to create/update/remove files you can use the [Contents resources](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents).

For example, [this section explains how to update a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file).

Comment: Thanks but actually I was found api of github. Problem is I can't find API for commit a file for bitbucket

Comment: @Thaina, you're looking for the Contents resources. I've updated my answer with a few links to the docs.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook "bitbucket" for "github" in your first remark. With bitbucket I don't think they've exposed updating files through their REST API, so you won't be able to use that. You could write your own server application that would use a git library to interact with your repositories and exposes the necessary actions through a REST API, but that's not a trivial thing to do ... Or you could implement your own bitbucket (Server) add-on to expose those REST calls, but that's not easy either.

Answer (score 4):

Bitbucket user here, you can EDIT/COMMIT your files in browser.

https://gyazo.com/ff3cb58bcc1cceda0306037989f32ab1

Answer (score 2):

Bitbucket has an online editor where you can change the file and commit right away. Check it out [here](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/05/14/edit-your-code-in-the-cloud-with-bitbucket/).

Answer (score 1):

[See the official response here:](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/8672/is-there-any-api-to-make-a-commit)

tldr:
They're working on expanding their API and have responded to an issue opened in 2013

EDIT: An endpoint to do this is now available!

Comment: IT'S READY, LET DO IT.

Answer (score 1):

[Update August 2021](https://twitter.com/github/status/1425505817827151872): just type <kbd>.</kbd> (dot)

> New shortcut: Press <kbd>.</kbd> on any GitHub repo.
>
> [image: dot]

That will launch [GitHub Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces) on your current repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can install on your local computer [`benweet/stackedit`](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit), a markdown javascript editor.

As [mentioned in the `README`](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit#stackedit-can),

> Publish your Markdown document on GitHub

(See more at [Publication](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/public/res/WELCOME.md#publication))

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benweet/stackedit/master/public/res/img/menu.png]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Power Editor for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213285/power-editor-for-bitbucket?hosting=server&tab=overview) for editing and commiting code from browser in bitbucket.